# unity lerp scale doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, scale, lerp

I am trying to make an object scale from zero to it's normal size when I instantiate it, so it will look like it popped to the screen.

So when the object start I get it's normal size then update it to zero, and then in update I am scaling it.

This is my code:

```
void Start()
{
    normalScale = transform.localScale;
    transform.localScale *= 0.1f;
}
void Update()
{
    transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale * 0.1f, transform.localScale, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
    // destroy item
    if (transform.localScale == normalScale)
    {
        transform.localScale = transform.localScale * 0.1f;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you mean `Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, normalScale, 5f * Time.deltaTime)`

Comment: +1 and (transform.localScale == normalScale) will probably never happen (calculated float being equal to calculated float is like winning on lottery, thanks to Epsilon), so do a >= instead

Comment: @Bart no, because at start I want to make the object small then enlarge it

Comment: @Mark I can't do '<=' operators to Vector3 it says

Comment: @Mark it'll never happen anyway because you'll never get `5f * Time.deltaTime == 1` - it'll never get that large.

Comment: Guys. OK, I understand that... The point was, don't make a statement "[calculated float] == [other calculated float]" like... ever. As it will never happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you're always changing from it's current scale, which of course you changed last update

```
transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale * 0.1f, transform.localScale, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
```

What you need to do is create two Vector3 outside of the update function, one for the start size, one for the final size

```
Vector3 start = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 end = new Vector3(1,1,1);
```

You'll also need a timer:

float lerpTime = 0;

Altogether you get

```
transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(start, end, lerpTime);
lerpTime += Time.deltaTime // times whatever multiplier you want for the speed
```

Comment: Vector3.one; instead of "new Vector3(1,1,1);" ?

Comment: Thank you, this works. can you explain a bit why if I set up the lerpTime to zero it starts over again and again?

Comment: @DramboHero it seems lerp is the most misunderstood function in unity. the t value is a "percentage" inbetween start and end clamped between 0 and 1
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/linear-interpolation

Comment: That's right, the last argument is a float between 0 and 1, think of this as 0% and 100% which correspond to your starting scale (0%) and your final scale(100%). Increasing the lerpTime on each update means bringing the scale a bit closer to the final scale. Naturally if you set it to 0 the scale is now your starting scale and so you should set lerpTime = 0 outside of the update function. A coroutine is useful here with a return value of null instead of using update.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html your 3rd parameter in

```
transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale * 0.1f, transform.localScale, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
```

is supposed to indicate the "fracJourney", in other words it should change from 0f to 1f to indicate the progress of your animation, but Time.deltaTime will give you the time since the last frame so that you probably see it jump around 0.005 (or whatever your frame rate is).

You need to add another variable to indicate the progress of your animation:

```
public float speed = 1.0F;
private float startTime;

void Start() {
    startTime = Time.time;
    normalScale = transform.localScale;
}

void Update()
{
    float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;

    transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3.zero, normalScale, distCovered);
    // destroy item
    if (transform.localScale >= normalScale)
    {
        startTime = Time.time; // Reset the animation
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to fix the first two parameters passed to the lerp. Your code is still going to endlessly shrink the target...

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code that are likely to be causing problems. The first is the start/end values you're passing in to the lerp:

```
Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale * 0.1f, transform.localScale, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
```

On your second frame, `.localScale` is roughly `(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)`. The *max* value of the lerp on your second frame is the value from your first frame. That means that your current code is endlessly shrinking the target - the opposite of what you wanted.

The other problem is the way you're handling the time. You're passing `5f * Time.deltaTime`, which is (probably) always going to be less than 1. This means you will never reach the maximum value.

So, to fix these, you need two things: first, you need to make sure your min/max values are *actually* min/max values, not arbitrary values in between. Second, you need to make sure your third parameter progresses smoothly from 0 to 1 over a defined time.

Something like this:

```
public float ScaleTime = 5f; // the time it'll take to grow, settable in the inspector

public float ScaleTime = 5f; // the time it'll take to grow, settable in the inspector

Vector3 _targetScale;
Vector3 _startScale;
float _currentLerp = 0f;

void Start()
{
    _targetScale = this.localScale;
    _startScale = _targetScale * 0.1f;
}

void Update()
{
    _currentLerp += Time.deltaTime * ScaleTime;

    if (_currentLerp < 1)
    {
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(_startScale, _targetScale, _currentLerp);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.localScale = _targetScale; // make sure we definitely hit the target size

        ... do whatever else you need to do here...
    }
}
```